# How to split a LineString to segments

Tags: python, postgis, geopandas, shapely

My data set consists of a `LineString` and I want to filter out the individual line segments of this `LineString`. More precisely, every single street segment.

Until now I have extracted the individual points from the data set and saved them in a separate list. Furthermore, I would like to collect these points again and create individual LineStrings from them to store them into a Geodataframe.
The data has this form:

```
LINESTRING (3275.284016199762 340555.8579582386, 3241.504528076811 340504.1348617533, 3245.415803206172 340501.457084205, 3280.414559049542 340552.7138220053, 3285.19053022
```

My problem with this is that I would have to create and explicitly save a separate `LineString` for each iteration.
Can anyone help me with this? Is there a better method for this?

```
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString

#Loop over LineString and gather Points
c=[]

for i in range(0,end):
    c.append(Point(route1.coords[i]))


iterator=len(c)
max=len(c)-1

#Loop to store LineStrings - got stuck here
for i in np.arange(0,iterator):
    if i<max:
        LineString([c[i], c[i+1]]).wkt

    else:
        break;
```

The output should look like this:

```
Linestring(Point A, Point B)  
Linestring(Point B, Point C)  
Linestring(Point C, Point D)  
...  
Linestring(Point Y, Point Z)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Speaking of Shapely, it doesn't provide a function to split a curve object (`LineString` or `LinearRing`) to segments, so you have to write your own. Here is an example of how you could do it using [`zip`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1663807/7851470) to iterate over pairs of [coordinates](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#coordinate-sequences) and [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) them to `LineString`'s:

```
from shapely.geometry import LineString, LinearRing


def segments(curve):
    return list(map(LineString, zip(curve.coords[:-1], curve.coords[1:])))


line = LineString([(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2)])
ring = LinearRing([(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (0, 1)])

line_segments = segments(line)
for segment in line_segments:
    print(segment)
# LINESTRING (0 0, 1 1)
# LINESTRING (1 1, 2 2)

ring_segments = segments(ring)
for segment in ring_segments:
    print(segment)
# LINESTRING (0 0, 1 0)
# LINESTRING (1 0, 1 1)
# LINESTRING (1 1, 0 1)
# LINESTRING (0 1, 0 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO.

You don't have to write code to split a `LineString`. Let PostGIS do the job :) The quick&dirty example below uses a [`CTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/queries-with.html) to [`ST_DumpPoints`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DumpPoints.html) from your `LineString`, and subsequently creates another line with path,path+1 using the window function [`lead()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-window.html):

```
WITH j AS (
  SELECT ST_DumpPoints('LINESTRING (10 10, 12 12, 14 14, 16 16, 18 18)') AS g
)
SELECT ST_AsText(point) FROM (
  SELECT ST_MakeLine((g).geom, lead((g).geom,1) OVER ()) AS point
  FROM j) i
WHERE i.point IS NOT NULL

            st_astext        
-------------------------
 LINESTRING(10 10,12 12)
 LINESTRING(12 12,14 14)
 LINESTRING(14 14,16 16)
 LINESTRING(16 16,18 18)
(4 Zeilen)
```